# WinSCP : How to enter a script parameter with spaces without resolving the double quotes on WinSCP script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, winscp

I am using a batch file to write the script.

```
echo open sftp://user:pass@cagprod/ >> script.tmp
echo option batch continue >> script.tmp
echo option confirm off >> script.tmp

echo cd /ccr/ccar_modsub/Unsecured_Production/CCAR_Models/Model_Code_Version/Acct_lvl/HK_CARD/Code >> script.tmp
echo get * "Y:\1. Documents\Automated file copying\%3\Code\" >> script.tmp

echo close >> script.tmp
echo exit >> script.tmp
"Y:\Winscp\winscp382.exe" /console /script=script.tmp /parameter
del script.tmp
```

I want %3 parameter (it contains spaces so I will have to call it using double quotes) resolved without any double quotes when i call it on command line as follows -

```
"i:\CAP_Profile\Desktop\Automation file copying\script2.bat" "Data setp\Code line"
```

Also, is there a better way of declaring variables for WinSCP script?

Comment: If you happen to ever read the help file for the `CALL` command you would have read this: `%~1         - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")`

Comment: This can also be done with `PowerShell` and `Posh-SSH`. https://www.business.com/articles/manage-files-over-sftp-powershell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%~3` expands input variable `%3` removing surrounding qoutes. You can also do a slightly cleaner script, by not having the double redirect to file in each line.

```
@echo off
>script.tmp (
  echo open sftp://user:pass@cagprod/
  echo option batch continue
  echo option confirm off
  echo cd /ccr/ccar_modsub/Unsecured_Production/CCAR_Models/Model_Code_Version/Acct_lvl/HK_CARD/Code
  echo get * "Y:\1. Documents\Automated file copying\%~3\Code\"
  echo close
  echo exit
 )
```

Also, as something to note in your original code. When doing redirects, be careful for your whitespace before redirect as any whitespace is actually transfered as part of the output, so though in most cases it would not matter, it can make a difference. To demonstrate that, simply run these from cmdline:

```
type nul>test_file.txt
echo Hello >> test_file.txt
```

Then do `notepad test_file.txt` and note the trailing space after `Hello` You can repeat the below to see no trailing whitespaces:

```
type nul>test_file.txt
echo Hello>>test_file.txt
```